# How does a process schedule its own threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, scheduling

After the Kernel schedules a process that has threads, How does said process schedule its own threads during its time splice?

Comment: Processes/threads do not schedule execution.  On commonly-available OS today, processes do not have 'time splices'.  TBH, terms like 'time slice' 'quantum' etc should be removed from usage since they give a hugely misleading impression of modern kernel thread scheduling:(

Answer (score 0):

For most modern kernels, the kernel only schedules threads, and processes are mostly just a container for the threads to execute inside (e.g. a container that contains a virtual address space, however many threads, and a few other scraps like file handles).

For some kernels (mostly very old unix kernels that existed before threads were invented) the kernel schedules processes and then a user-space library emulates threads. For this to work properly all of the "blocking" system calls (e.g. `write()`) have to be replaced by asynchronous system calls (e.g. `aio_write()`) so that other threads in the process can be given CPU time; however I wouldn't want to assume it works properly (e.g. if any thread blocks, then maybe all threads in the process block).

Also it may not work when there's multiple CPUs (kernel gives a process one CPU, but then from the kernel's perspective that process is running and can't use a second CPU). There are sophisticated work-arounds for this (to support "M:N threading") but it's just easier and better to fix the scheduler so it works with threads. Fortunately/unfortunately this didn't matter much in the early days because very few computers had more than one CPU anyway.

Lastly; it doesn't work for thread priorities - e.g. one process might keep CPU busy executing an unimportant/low priority thread while another process doesn't get that CPU time when it desperately needs it for an important/high priority thread. This occurs because no process knows about threads belonging to other processes and the kernel only knows about processes and not threads.

Of course these are also the reasons why every kernel adopted "kernel schedules threads and not processes" (and those that didn't died).

Answer (score 0):

It's down to jargon definitions, but threads are simply a bunch of processes sharing an address space. Older Unixes even called them Light Weight Processes.

With that classical understanding of threads, the answer is that, these days, it's the OS that does the scheduling and each thread gets its own timeslices.

**Extras**

Some OSes do things to "the whole process" - e.g. Windows will give the process that has mouse focus a priority boost (all it's threads get dynamically notched up a few priority places), to make that application appear to be more sprightly (this goes back to Windows 3).

Other operating systems will increase the priority of a thread dynamically, to solve priority inversion situations. This is where a low priority thread that has control of a resource (I/O, or perhaps a semaphore) is blocking a higher priority thread from running (because the resource is not available. This is the priority inversion, and it's solved by the OS boosting the priority of the blocking thread until it gives up the required resource.

Answer (score -1):

Either the kernel schedules the threads or the kernel schedules processes simulates thread by scheduling it own threads.

Usually, the process schedules its own threads using a library that sets timers. When the timer handler saves the current "thread's" registers then loads a new set of registers from another "thread."

Comment: I don't understand the first paragraph.

Comment: @KarimKamel that's because it's unclear.  The second paragraph is unclear, misleading and, for most common OS, wrong.

Comment: You get a choice. Either the kernel schedules the threads or the application has to schedule its own threads. You are asking about the latter.